# Join 2 tables and show row data in individual columns

Tags: sql-server, join, select, sql-server-2019

I got a peculiar requirement to create a SQL query joining 2 tables as below

`customer` is the first table.  This table holds the primary (p) and other (o) customers.  The field `cust_id` creates the link between these 2 tables.  There can be a maximum or 2 other customers for a primary customer.

```
customer
 --------------------------------
| id  | cust_id   | year  | type |
|-----|-----------|-------|------|
| 1   | 111111    | 1977  | p    |
| 2   | 222222    | 1978  | p    |
| 3   | 333333    | 1970  | o    |
| 4   | 444444    | 1968  | o    |
| 5   | 555555    | 1979  | o    |
 --------------------------------

other_customer
 --------------------------------
| id | cust_id  | other_cust_id  |
|----|----------|----------------|
| 1  | 111111   | 333333         |
| 2  | 111111   | 444444         |
| 3  | 222222   | 555555         |
 --------------------------------
```

I want to select all customers from `customer` table `where type='p'` and produce a result like below

```
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  cust_id  | primay_customer_year | other_customer1_id | other_customer1_year | other_customer2_id | other_customer2_year |
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  111111   | 1977                 | 333333             | 1970                 | 444444             | 1968                 |
|  222222   | 1978                 | 555555             | 1979                 |                    |                      |
 --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

How can I achieve that using a SQL query.  The database we are using in MSSQL 2019

Comment: This is PIVOT. It is strongly recommended to convert plain rowset to its pivot representation on the client side using client reporting service. While performing on the SQL server side this needs in dynamic SQL usage.

Comment: What RDBMS server are you using?

Comment: Please update your question's tags with which database system and version you're using.